# Let m ≥ 2 be an integer. Show that if a is an integer such that gcd(a, m) = ̸= 1, there exists [x]* in Zm such that [a]·[x]=[0].

Tags: elementary-number-theory

--> * [x] is a non-zero congruence class

**I've gotten this far:**

since d|m, m=kd, k=m/d

[k] is non-zero since 0 < k < m.

[a] . [k] = [0] because...

I'm not sure how to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

We have $a=a^\ast d$, $m=m^\ast d$. Then $a m^\ast=(a^\ast d)m^\ast=a^\ast(dm\ast)=a^\ast m$. It follows that 
$$[a][m^\ast]=[a][m]=[a][0]=[0].$$
Since $0\lt m^\ast \lt m$, we have $[m^\ast]\ne [0]$.

Comment: But [x] has to be a non-zero congruence class. and [m] in Zm = [0]

Comment: We have proved that $[a][m^\ast]=[0]$, and since $0\lt m^\ast\lt m$, we have $[m^\ast]\ne [0]$.

Comment: You are welcome. I added a little to the answer, so that it will also be clear to others.